# What is the name of this huge high-power test equipment?

Tags: identification, high-voltage, test-equipment, high-power

It seems very old, maybe more than 50 years, and it doesn't have an information plate.

[image]

Comment: Could be a Tesla Coil, or a Van De Graaff generator.

Comment: What a cool piece of kit. It can make extremely high voltages. Use with care.

Comment: yeah sure. what is its scientific name? for searching and finding more info about it.

Comment: Seems most likely to be a Van de Graaf generator.

Comment: Most VdGGs have much slimmer shafts relative to the capacitive cap. [images here](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=simg:CAESgAEafgsQsIynCBpiCmAIAxIo8wzyDJENkA30DIsNhw3vDI8N3wySNsch4SeONvAn7if-J_1k12CeEPhowNQKL1DG6XrYEQlDC00XwnXNcT3EjVlnDDtNOh-lmYjBd8Lqzfkc0eilKASWYVcIsIAQMCxCOrv4IGgoKCAgBEgThSyoKDA&sxsrf=APq-WBtUiDYn14FJkoVbRU-vhp0axC6tIQ:1645864976394&q=van+de+graaf+&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVhJDq_Jz2AhVcSGwGHXUyC3wQjJkEegQIAhAC&biw=1827&bih=1028&dpr=2)

Comment: Send it to me, I'll figure it out.

Comment: @MikeSchroedel do you mean more photos? how can i send directly?

Comment: If you walk towards it and your hair starts to stand up, walk away from it and find out how to discharge it safely.

Comment: My Kirby vacuum cleaner!

Comment: Could well be a voltage divider/probe to allow measurment of an ehv system.